# Set colored border for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want my tableview cell to have colored border and rounded corners. Thats what i tried:

```
 // Color

    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"dbd7d7"].CGColor];

    // Rounded corners

    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"dbd7d7"].CGColor;
```

However, there is odd "white triangles" on right and left borders. Please take a look:

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: look at the view debugger, and see what's behind that layer. Ther must be one view behind the border. MAke that view background color as clear color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the table view's background color is clear and check that `cell.opaque = NO;`

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.opaque = NO; not helped((

Comment: not cell background, the answer says to set table background color @EvgeniyKleban

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad` method

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:UIColor.clearColor];
```